# Find what's not provable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Consider the following:

```
link(step1, step2) .
link(step2, step3) .
link(step3, step4) .

goal(X) :- \+ link(X, _) .
```

I would like `goal` functor to represent a step that is not at the beginning of a link.

But when I try :

```
| ?- goal(X).

no
```

(instead of telling me that step4 is a solution)

The following, however, does evaluate to `yes`:

```
goal(step4).
```

I'm guessing that's because I'm asking prolog to find what it *can't* find (*sigh*…)

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble comes with Prolog not knowing what your universe of valid values of `X` could be. In this particular example, you could do it by defining what a valid step is:

```
valid_step(X) :- link(X, _) ; link(_, X).
```

This would then help you tell `goal` what to choose from for the "universe of valid steps":

```
goal(X) :- valid_step(X), \+ link(X, _).
```

Yielding:

```
| ?- goal(X).

X = step4

yes
| ?-
```

Or, if more specifically, you really mean to find `X` which is present as a destination link but not a source link:

```
goal(X) :- link(_, X), \+ link(X, _).
```

It depends upon the big picture of what your facts are, what they mean, and what the semantics of `goal` really are.

Perhaps a more suitable way to define valid steps, if the `link` relation isn't what logically definesto what a valid step is, would be to make `valid_step` a set of facts, instead of the predicate I show above:

```
valid_step(step1).
valid_step(step2).
valid_step(step3).
valid_step(step4).
valid_step(step5).
```

So this is a simple, completely independent definition of what a valid step is, and can be used by other relations (predicates) that need this information.

It may be tempting to do:

```
valid_steps([step1,step2,step3,step4,step5]).
```

And then:

```
goal(X) :- valid_steps(Valid), member(X, Valid), \+ link(X, _).
```

But I believe the list of discrete facts is preferable.

Comment: Right. And if I wanted to include steps that have no links, I'd go for `step(X) :- X = step1 ; X = step2 ; X = step3 ; X = step4 ; X = step5 .` ?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre Ah, no I'd define them individually. I updated my answer accordingly.